# I am looking for a story about a shrinking demon

Tags: story-identification

I read this tongue-in-cheek short story during the '60's. For some reason the main character is being harassed by a demon. He discovers that he can get rid of the creature - or cage it or something - by drawing a pentagram on the floor and keeping the thing outside it. No matter how small the hero draws the pentagram the demon shrinks itself to fit. Somehow he manages to draw a pentagram on the demon's body and it shrinks out of sight.

Comment: “I am looking for a story about a shrinking demon” — aren’t we all!

Comment: Hi Lee! Any feedback on Organic Marble's answer? Or does the search continue? :)

Comment: It seems you are once again active on the site. Consider accepting the answer below!

Answer (score 24):

Larry Niven's [Convergent Series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53821) is the story you seek.

> Eventually he'd look down and see the pentagram.  Part of it was in
> plain sight.  But it wouldn't help him..[omission]...I had drawn it on
> his bulging belly.